# Change email text color in moderncv

Tags: color, moderncv, email

I'm having an issue trying to change the text color of the email in `moderncv`.

I defined my own color like this :

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
```

Then I add the email like this :

```
\email{\textcolor{mycolor}{email@gmail.com}}
```

> **main.tex, line 45 Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `rgb(0,0,0)'. See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help. ... l.45 \makecvtitle Try typing
>     to proceed If that doesn't work, type  X   to
>   quit.**

If I try it on the phone instead, it works

```
\phone[mobile]{\textcolor{mycolor}{+123456789}}
```

[image]

But I have no idea why it doesn't work for email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the patch I used in your last question to solve this problem too.

Add the code

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvhead} % <cmd>
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}} % <search>
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\textcolor{mycolor}{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
  } % <replace>
  {}{} % <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

to your preamble. So with the following MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle[right]{classic}
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.8cm}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{24}{0}\bfseries\upshape}
\firstname{\vspace{2mm}John\vspace{2mm}}
\lastname{Doe}

\address{24 Groove Street, LA, USA}
\email{john.doe@gmail.com}
\photo[50pt][1pt]{photo}

\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\phone[mobile]{\textcolor{mycolor}{+123456789}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvhead} % <cmd>
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}} % <search>
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\textcolor{mycolor}{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
  } % <replace>
  {}{} % <success><failure>
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]